# GoogleApiClient force full disconnect

Tags: android, google-api-client

In my game, I use `GoogleApiClient.connect()` and `GoogleApiClient.disconnect()` but when I connect I can't choose my account, the first choose fix the account. I want to be able to choose my account for play. I'm implementing the saved games code and want be able to choose my account when i reconect.

My device save my account for all games. I can force my game to select the account?

My code:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(a)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(cfl)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
            .setViewForPopups(a.findViewById(android.R.id.content))
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

public static void desconectarGoogle(){
    if(mGoogleApiClient!=null && isSignedIn())
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to call the methods `mGoogleApiClient.signOut()` and `mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccount()` in your disconnect function. Reference to the bottom of this page: [Implementing Sign-in in Your Google Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin)

Comment: clearDefaultAccount is deprecated and your code dont work, sign out and clear default cannot resolve.

Comment: The correct code fos signOut is Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient); but dont force to choose account when reconect.

Comment: Ok sorry, the code works, is my android studio, somtimes not update the game :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok the code for force is mGoogleApiClient.signOut(), work and force select account :)